# Laurent Series Regions

Tags: laurent-series

Suppose that I'm trying to construct Laurent series for the following complex function:

$$f(z)=(z^2+4)^{\frac{1}{3}}$$

Since I have a 1/3 exponent, this means that my branch points must extend to infinity when I define my branch cut (to make f single-valued).  So, even though I may define a Laurent series such that |z|>2, it is not valid because the branch cut introduces discontinuities, correct?  Is this reasoning the right way to think about it?  I ask because I constructed the Laurent series in the region |z| > 2, programmed it in Matlab, and I'm getting the correct results.

Here's what I calculated for |z| > 2:

$$f(z)=z^{\frac{2}{3}}\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\Gamma(4/3)}{n!\Gamma(4/3-n)}(\frac{2}{z})^{2n}$$

Comment: Yes, that is the question: whether the laurent series for |z| > 2 is valid or not.

Comment: The answer to which is: no, it is not valid. If you'd like a more concrete answer, I suggest that you add your Laurent series for $|z|>2$ to the question.

Comment: Alright, I added it.

Comment: Laurent series are of the form: $\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} a_nz^n$. They do not have fractional powers. Note that your function is analytic in $\lvert z\rvert>2$, and hence it can be express as $\sum_{n=-\infty}^{0} a_nz^n$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function 
$$
F(z) = z^{-2/3} f(z) = (1+4z^{-2})^{1/3}
$$
admits a single-valued holomorphic branch in $|z|>2$,  which you can indeed expand into a Laurent series. This is the series in your post.

However, multiplying by $z^{2/3}$ you do not get a Laurent series for the original $f$. By its definition, a Laurent series does not have fractional powers of $z$.

So: you have a representation for (multi-valued) $f$ in terms of (multi-valued) $z^{2/3}$. It's just not a Laurent series of $f$.

Comment: Laurent series are of the form: $\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} a_nz^n$. They do not have fractional powers. Note that your function is analytic in $\lvert z\rvert>2$, and hence it can be express as $\sum_{n=-\infty}^{0} a_nz^n$

Comment: How is it analytic in |z| > 2 if the branch cut is there?  I thought that a discontinuity prevents analyticity.

Comment: @user108149 If you are asking Y.S.S., you should use @ in  your comment to notify him.

Comment: Right, @user108149. The branch cut means it isn't analytic in (all of) $\lvert z\rvert > 2$.

Comment: Alright, so I'm really confused.  @127.0.9.6 I agree with you, but this YSS guy claims that I can form a Laurent series in |z| > 2.  What's correct? o_0

Comment: @user108149 I think Yiorgos was referring to function $F$ in my answer.

Comment: @127.0.9.6 Alright, thanks for your help.